# If you are asked to participate in review, is your submission likely to be accepted?

Tags: peer-review, conference

If you are asked to participate in review of a conference paper to which you have yourself submitted a paper, what is likelihood that *your* paper has been accepted?

Or is it possible that they would ask an author of the rejected work to participate in the review of remaining submissions?

Comment: Can I ask why you are assuming your paper has been reviewed before the others? My assumption would be that reviewers for papers would have to be chosen before any of them are reviewed, and though not entirely independent, the reviewers should be chosen based on their past work and ability to peer review for the field; the papers should be accepted based on the merit of those papers. Certainly there could be some overlap ("Professor X is well respected, therefore he gets asked to review, and also everyone assumes his work is perfect."), but I am doubting you fit in that category.

Comment: Well. It's my first time I am being asked to help with review. Not familiar yet with how reviewers are selected.

Comment: I could see them selecting reviewers from the pool of submitted papers, but there is a pretty clear problem with them selecting only accepted reviewers: who was the egg that got accepted before anyone reviewed anything? If they are selecting reviewers now, it seems the papers have not yet been reviewed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's unlikely that a decision has been made yet about your paper.  At least in the sorts of conferences I'm familiar with, no decisions are made before the program committee meeting (except possibly eliminating completely inappropriate submissions, such as crackpot or off-topic work).  This means all reviewers are recruited before any decisions are made, since all the reviews are needed at the meeting, so being asked to review supplies no information about whether your submission will be accepted.

The only correlation is that you shouldn't be asked to review something too close to your own submission, to avoid conflicts of interest.  If you are worried about that, you could always ask the program committee member who recruited you as a reviewer.  It's possible that they just screwed up, without realizing the potential conflict, but it's more likely that they think this paper is far enough from your submission to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

I support the existing answer but would like to add:

The fact that they had a good enough opinion of you to invite you to be a reviewer does increase the probability of acceptance of your own submission.  This is like one of those classic conditional probability questions.

The invitation to review is positive feedback, and you may take this as a shot in the arm.  It's always helpful to get a boost in one's self-confidence!